# Sending data from Screen over Socket IO?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, getusermedia, web-mediarecorder

I have been googling around but cannot find a clear answer to this.

I am making a chrome extension which records tabs. The idea is to stream getUserMedia to the backend using Websockets (specifically Socket.io) where the backend writes to a file until a specific condition (a value in the backend) is set.

The problem is, I do not know how I would call the backend with a specific ID and also, how would I correctly write to the file without corrupting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending the output from MediaRecorder, via a websocket, to your back end.

Presumably you do this from within MediaRecorder's `ondataavailable` handler.

It's quite easy to stuff that data into a websocket:

```js
function ondataavailable ( event ) {
  event.data.arrayBuffer().then ( buf => {socket.emit('media', buf) })
}
```

In the backend you must concatenate all the data you receive, in the order of reception, to a media file. This media file likely has a video/webm MIME type; if you give it the `.webm` filename extension most media players will handle it correctly. Notice that the media file will be useless if it doesn't contain all the Blobs in order. The first few Blobs contain metadata needed to make sense of the stream.  This is easy to do by appending each received data item to the file.

Server-side you can use the `socket.id` attribute to make up a file name; that gives you a unique file for each socket connection. Something like this sleazy poorly-performing non-debugged not-production-ready code will do that.

```js
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  if (!socket.filename) 
     socket.filename = path.join(__dirname, 'media', socket.id + '.webm))

  socket.on('filename', (name) => {
     socket.filename = path.join(__dirname, 'media', name + '.webm))
  })
  socket.on('media', (buf) => {
    fs.appendFile(buf, filename)
  })
})
```

On the client side you could set the filename with this.

```
socket.emit('filename', 'myFavoriteScreencast')
```

Comment: Hi! This actually helped me out alot! Tysm for the answer. One last thing. It seems the final blob data does not get sent (tested on Chrome which is my main browser). Backend script: https://pastebin.com/T5HenViU - Frontend Script: https://pastebin.com/YkH9RhM4 When I play back the video, it does not show how long the video is and i cant skip through. It seems the final blob is not being sent. How come?

Comment: The files you get from MediaRecorder don't have metadata showing their length. That's because they're continuous streams -- their length isn't known when they start. If you can play them, they're correct. There's a software package called mkvToolNix you can use to take a look at their structure.

Comment: Interesting because with Chrome, I tend to get glitchy files but i think Firefox handles them well (and even shows me the length). Isnt the mediaRecorder.stop() suppose to send the final length and any other data?